# Use a css3 media query in a Sass @for loop

Tags: css, media-queries, sass

Is it possible?

Ex:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
  @media screen and (min-width: #{$i * 240}) { 
    width: {$i * 240 + (20*($i-1)) } ;
  }
}
```

But I keep getting

```
Invalid CSS after "...nd (min-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#{$i * 240}) { ..."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use variables in media queries with Sass 3.2 and above. You can find the version you are using by running this in Terminal:

```
gem list | grep sass
```

You can install the 3.2 alpha by running:

```
(sudo) gem install sass --pre
```

I'm assuming you're looking to use pixels as well so once you have 3.2+ installed, you could clean up your code to be:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
  @media screen and (min-width: $i * 240px) { 
    width: $i * 240px + (20*($i - 1));
  }
}
```

Notice multiplying by `240px` instead of just `240` and the space added between `$i - 1`